# Importing HTML files into SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, html, import

I am in the process of moving an intranet website from a outdated platform to SharePoint. I have the HTML files from the previous site that I am going to clean up and would like to bulk upload into Pages (its about 350 pages). I have multiple layouts but for this purpose I am just going to use the simplest one. I haven't found an easy way to do this. Does anyone have a solution? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Which version will you migrate to? SharePoint online or SharePoint server?

If you want to migrate html files from outdated platform to SharePoint server, there is no direct way to migrate, we suggest you store all files in local folder, then use powershell to bulk upload to SharePoint library.

For detailed information, please refer to :

https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2012/10/bulk-upload-files-to-sharepoint-using-powershell.html

If you are ready to migrate to SharePoint Online, please refer to:

https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/06/upload-files-to-sharepoint-online-using-powershell.html